# DAX AverageX where table dimension is reduced by one

Tags: dax

I'm trying to find the right way to structure a DAX formula to compute a specific average.  I think I might be able to construct the average more or less explicitly by using a sum/count construction, but I'm wondering if averagex with an appropriate set of table filters might get the job done.

Specifically, my problem can be explained like this: I'm trying to compute the average cost of a car in DAX, but my data includes the cost of all the components individually (call it body, wheels and engine for now).

```
 
Name  Year Part   Cost
Alice 2000 Engine $10 
Alice 2000 Wheels $5
Alice 2000 Body $25
Alice 2001 Engine $8
Alice 2001 Wheels $6
Alice 2001 Body $2
Bob   2000 Engine $10
Bob   2000 Wheels $5
Bob   2000 Body $25
Bob   2001 Engine $8
Bob   2001 Wheels $6
Bob   2001 Body $2
```

Is there any way to tell DAX that I want to first sum across all the components of the car first, and then compute averages on the data set where the dimensionality of the data has been reduced by one (only the "part" dimension removed)?

For example, the average cost for Alice then would yield 
((10+5+25)+(8+6+2))/2 = 28
While if I had a pivot table constructed per name and per year, it would show
Alice 2000 40
Alice 2001 16
etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... it works in the case where Name,Year provides a unique combination.

```
[nCombinations]:=COUNTROWS(SUMMARIZE(Table1,Table1[Name],Table1[Year]))
[TotalCost]:=SUM(Table1[Cost])
[AverageCost]:=CALCULATE([TotalCost]/[nCombinations])
```

Create a PivotTable with [Name] and [Year] on rows,
Then add [nCombinations] [TotalCost] and [AverageCost] in the body.

```
Row        nCombinations        TotalCost    AverageCost

Alice               2            56            28

2000                1            40            40

2001                1            16            16

Bob                 2            56            28

2000                1            40            40

2001                1            16            16

Grand Total         4           112            28
```